# I can't make my sprite land on top of my platform

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, monogame, platform

Here's my Game1.cs code. My goal was to make the sprite "player" land on platforms but it's not working. When I use an image that is not a spritesheet it works. What am I doing wrong here? T_T I've checked out lots of references but still cant figure it out. Thank you! Our final presentation is on Monday so I'm quite desperate. I may not pass our GameDev subject.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;


namespace Basa_Game
{



    public class Game1 : Game
    {

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SoundEffect effect;
        enum GameState
        {
            Menu,
            Playing,
            Options,
        }

        GameState CurrentGameState = GameState.Menu;
        cButton btnPlay,btnControls,btnCredits,btnQuit;
        Animation player;
        Player2 player2;
        Character sample;

        List <Platform> platforms = new List<Platform>();
        KeyboardState ks;
        float elapsed;
        float delay = 200f;
        int frames = 0;

        Texture2D menuTexture;
        Rectangle destRect, sourceRect;

        Texture2D mapTexture;
        Rectangle mapRectangle;

        Texture2D tile1Texture;
        Rectangle tile1Rectangle;

        int screenWidth = 1366;
        int screenHeight =768;

        Vector2 position = new Vector2();


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.HiDef;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1366, 768);
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            base.Initialize();
        }


        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            menuTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("menu2");
            sample = new Character(Content.Load<Texture2D>("caren whole"), new Vector2(50, 50));
            player = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("basawalk"), new Vector2(200, 200), 180, 110);
            player2 = new Player2(Content.Load<Texture2D>("right2"), new Vector2(1200, 640), 180, 110);
            position = new Vector2(400, 400);
            mapTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level1");
            mapRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1366,768);

            tile1Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("1");
            tile1Rectangle = new Rectangle(150, 540, 177, 44);


            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(20, 640)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(200, 550)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(650, 450)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(120, 450)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(900, 535)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(100, 200)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(400, 450)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(1000, 200)));
            platforms.Add(new Platform(Content.Load<Texture2D>("1"), new Vector2(1090, 450)));


            IsMouseVisible = true;
            btnPlay = new cButton(Content.Load<Texture2D>("play"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
            btnPlay.setPosition(new Vector2(760, 320));

            btnControls = new cButton(Content.Load<Texture2D>("btnControl"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
            btnControls.setPosition(new Vector2(760, 450));
            screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
            screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;



        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();

            switch (CurrentGameState)
            { 
                case GameState.Menu:
                    Animate(gameTime);
                    sourceRect = new Rectangle(1366 * frames, 0, 1366, 768);
                    if (btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
                    btnPlay.Update(mouse);
                    btnControls.Update(mouse);
                    break;

                case GameState.Playing:
                    foreach (Platform platform in platforms)
                        if (player.rectangle.isOnTopOf(platform.rectangle))
                        {
                            player.velocity.Y = 0f;
                            player.hasJump = false;
                        }
                      player.Update(gameTime);
                    break;

            }


            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            switch (CurrentGameState)
            {
                case GameState.Menu:
                    spriteBatch.Draw(menuTexture,destRect,sourceRect, Color.White);
                    btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
                    btnControls.Draw(spriteBatch);
                    break;
                case GameState.Playing:

            spriteBatch.Draw(mapTexture, mapRectangle, Color.White);

            foreach (Platform platform in platforms)
               platform.Draw(spriteBatch);
          sample.Draw(spriteBatch);
            player.Draw(spriteBatch);
            player2.Draw(spriteBatch);
                    break;
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
        public void Animate(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            elapsed += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
            if (elapsed >= delay)
            {
                if (frames >= 2)
                {
                    frames = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    frames++;
                }
                elapsed = 0;


            }
        }

    }
}

static class RectangleHelper
{
    const int penetrationMargin = 5;
    public static bool isOnTopOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return (r1.Bottom >= r2.Top - penetrationMargin &&
            r1.Bottom <= r2.Top + 1 &&
            r1.Right >= r2.Left + 5 &&
            r1.Left <= r2.Right - 5);
    }
}
```

And Here is my Animation.cs where I put the player movements and stuff.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Basa_Game
{
    class Animation
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Rectangle rectangle;
        public Vector2 position;
        public Vector2 origin;
        public Vector2 velocity;

        SpriteEffects effect = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;

        int currentFrame;
        int frameHeight = 110;
        int frameWidth = 180;

        float time;
        float interval=80f;

       public bool hasJump;


        public Animation(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPostion, int newFrameHeigth, int newFrameWidth)
        {
            texture = newTexture;
            position = newPostion;
            frameHeight = newFrameHeigth;
            frameWidth = newFrameWidth;
            hasJump = true;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            position += velocity;
            rectangle = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
            origin = new Vector2(rectangle.Width / 2, rectangle.Height / 2);
            position = position + velocity;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                AnimateRight(gameTime);
                velocity.X = 1;
            }
            else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                AnimateLeft(gameTime);
                velocity.X = -1;
            }
            else velocity.X = 0f;
            if (rectangle.X <= 0)
                rectangle.X = 0;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && hasJump == false)
            {
                position.Y -= 10f;
                velocity.Y = -5f;
                hasJump = true;
            }

            if (hasJump == true)
            {
                float i = 1;
                velocity.Y += 0.15f * i;
            }

            if (position.Y + texture.Height >= 768)
                hasJump = false;

            if (hasJump == false)
                velocity.Y = 0f;

        }

        public void AnimateRight(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            time += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 2;
            effect = SpriteEffects.None;
            if (time > interval)
            {
                currentFrame++;
                time = 0;
                if (currentFrame > 3)
                    currentFrame = 0;
            }
        }
        public void AnimateLeft(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            time += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 2;

            effect = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;

            if (time > interval)
            {
                currentFrame++;
                time = 0;
                if (currentFrame > 3)
                    currentFrame = 0;
            }
        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, rectangle, Color.White, 0f, origin, 1.0f, effect, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems as if you're just checking if the player is on top of the platform.  You should instead check if the player ***intersects*** the platform during that frame, plus some offsets if need be.  From the looks of it, your platforms are probably very thin, so the player will end up passing through  the platform before the game logic can check if they're on top of it.

Comment: I tried changing the .isOnTopOf to .Intersects but my player still doesnt land on Top. Also, yeah. My platforms are thin but it works when I used an image that isn't a sprite.. Even if the image is big ..

Comment: `.Intersects()` still might not work if the player moves further than the *length of the platform on that axis*.  instead, check if the player ended up passing through the platform during the frame.  I.e., use some maths to determine if the player would've ended up intersecting it *at some point* during that frame.  a good example of this is SM64's quarter steps (Mario's movement is updated 4 times per frame)

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't know what to do here. It would be great if I could see a code. Our instructor just gave us tutorial videos taken from youtube and expected us to create a complete 3 level game. Tsk. xD! Thank you for the help though.And tomorrows the deadline too.